# I have encounter an error "Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)"

Tags: linux, terminal

[image]

when i run sudo apt update

It shows :-
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: This seems like a recent [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/409) that needs to be resolved by a developer. I don't need to update the package at the moment. So for now I have removed http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code repo from the list of other repos that I update from. After I did that I was able to run `sudo apt update` with no problem. This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository) might be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue too today. After reading a bunch of other threads on it. It is in most cases have to do with network connectivity and in my case an issue on Microsoft's end. After half an hour or so it resolved by itself.

Comment: It worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Software&Updates - Other Software - find something  http://packages.microsoft.com... and uncheck this

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, use vim/nano to edit the source.list file.

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
```

Comment the line with `#`

```
# deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
```

save it `:wq` and re-run the update.

This solution is discussed in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/lgufql/how_to_block_new_microsoft_repo_which_now_comes/)

⚠️ By running the `chattr +i` cmd found in **Reddit** you will restrict the future edit for the file, use `chattr -i` to make it editable.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It automatically resolved after 1-2 hours. There was an issue commit of the new build Microsoft vscode.

Comment: I have the same issue but instead of the microsoft link it says "http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages" among others.

Answer (score 0):

You just had to renew the the apt repository and signing key.
have a look here:

```
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux
```

the following code will fix your problem:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg
```

Comment: Will this work with Linux Mint?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem in WSL of Debian, Ubuntu2004 or Ubuntu2204, when I execute `sudo apt update`.

For Debian, I install the `ca-certificates.deb`,`apt-transport-https` together with their dependencies `openssl.deb` manually, which were download from https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages.

Then I replace the `http` in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `https`.

Finally, execute `sudo apt update`, `Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT'` never appears.